# Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Attachment' System.Net.Mail

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am getting this error `Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Attachment'` and I cannot understand why.

This is the code to add new attachments:

```
Private mAttachments(0 To 10) As String

Dim idx As Integer

RaiseEvent Status("A adicionar anexos à mensagem...")
For idx = 1 To UBound(mAttachments)
    If Len(Dir(mAttachments(idx))) = 0 Then
        RaiseEvent SendFailed("Error!", 0)
        Exit Function
    Else
        'add an attachment
        mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(mAttachments(idx))
    End If
Next
```

I am getting the error here `(mAttachments(idx))`

The problem might be `Private mAttachments(0 To 10) As String`, but can't understand what I need to do.

Comment: Start at the "Remarks" section of the documentation for the [MailMessage.Attachments Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments?view=net-5.0) for instructions.

Comment: Can it work like this? `mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(mAttachments(idx)))` @AndrewMorton

Comment: @Rekcs: Yes, if the string array contains the paths to the attachment files. Btw, you know that you initiallize it with a length of 11 not 10? In general you should better use a `List(Of String)` if you don't know the size before. Yo're also using old VB syntax instead of VB.NET. You could use a simple [`For Each`-loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement) here.

Answer (score -3):

Visit http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5486

Please try:

AttachmentFile As String = "" // 1 file

AttachmentFiles As ArrayList = Nothing // Mutil file

Comment: No one should have to follow a link to understand an answer. Links can be provided for additional information but an answer should be a self-contained solution to the question as asked.